# Incorrect LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I am facing problem while writing a LINQ expression. 
I want to filter Rules from following lists (packages and rules) but the result I am getting is not correct.
Please help me rewrite the expression for expected result mentioned below.

```
public class Package
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string PackageKey {get;set;}
}

public class Rule
{
    public string Key1 {get;set;}
    public string Key2 {get;set;}
}

public Class RuleEntity
{
    public List<string> Keys {get;set;}
}

var rules = new  List<Rule>
{
    new Rule
    {
        Key1 = "001",
        Key2 = "002", 
    },
    new Rule
    {
        Key1 = "001",
        Key2 = "003", 
    },
    new Rule
    {
        Key1 = "004",
        Key2 = "005", 
    },
    new Rule
    {
        Key1 = "006",
        Key2 = "008", 
    }
};

var packages = new List<Package>
{
    new Package
    {
        Id = 1,
        PackageKey = 001
    },
    new Package
    {
        Id = 1,
        PackageKey = 002
    }
};

var filteredRules = new List<RuleEntity>();

filteredRules.AddRange(packages.SelectMany(p => rules.Where(r => p.PackageKey.Equals(r.Key1) || p.PackageKey.Equals(r.Key2))
            .Select(r => new RuleEntity{ Keys = new List<string>{r.Key1, r.Key2}})
));


//Result from above expression is this.
filteredRules
{
    Keys{ "001", "002" },
    Keys{ "001", "003" }
}


//Result Expected is :
filteredRules
{
    Keys{ "001", "002" }
}
```

FilteredRules should only contain Rules whose Key lies in Package list. If there is only one package in the packages list there should be no rule in filteredRules.

Comment: Do you only want rules where both keys are in the package list?

Comment: You'd still get a result for one Package if a rule has the same `Key1` and `Key2` as the package right?  Unless that just never happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
rules.Where(r => packages.Any(p => p.PackageKey == r.Key1) 
            && packages.Any(p => p.PackageKey == r.Key2))
    .Select(r => new RuleEntity
        { 
            Keys = new List<string>
            {
                r.Key1, 
                r.Key2
            }
        });
```

But it would be better to have a HashSet of the keys upfront to make the lookup quicker

```
var keys = new HashSet<string>(packages.Select(p => p.PackageKey));
```

Then the `Where` is reduced to

```
Where(r =>  keys.Contains(r.Key1) && keys.Contains(r.Key2))
```

Comment: Good idea on using a hashset for efficiency.

Answer (score 3):

Your `SelectMany` seems to be over complicating things. You are wanting to filter the rules so start with that and go from there:

```
rules.Where(x=>packages.Any(y=>y.PackageKey==x.Key1) && packages.Any(y=>y.PackageKey==x.Key2));
```

This will return any rules where key1 has a match in your packages list and key2 also has a match in your packages list.